# How to merge contents of cell into one?

Tags: excel, merge, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Does anybody know how to combine the contents of cells into one but still each piece of information in one separate line?

I have over 100 spreadsheets in which I have to do the same so I cannot do it manually.

[image: picture example]

Comment: No its from 1 to an X number, it always changes. But the last row its around 100 to 600... And the sheets are in different books. Thats one of the biggest issues...

Answer (score 2):

`=A1&CHAR(10)&A2&CHAR(10)&A3&CHAR(10)&A4`

with wrapping`*` will get you from A1:A4 to D1 but obviously may not suit your actual dataset. However, merged cells have been called an abomination (they are best avoided) so perhaps the one formula would suit in 100+ different spreadsheets - specially if all in the same book.

`*` Home > Cells - Format, Format Cells, Alignment, Text Control, tick Wrap text

Comment: thanks pnuts but i need each number in a single line, as shown in the image. Not one after the other in one line..